# Problem with external monitor

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, external-monitor, xps, displayport

Since yesterday I have weired problems using my external monitor (Benq 19" connected via DVI over DVI->HDMI cable and HDMI->Mini DisplayPort-Adapter) with Ubuntu 14.04. Until then I could use this monitor w/o problems. I did quite some research but could not really find a solution

There are two scenarios of this problem:

1. When I connect the monitor to my Laptop (DELL XPS 13 3. Gen) while beeing logged into unity the monitor is detected and tried to connect to as screen extension. But the screen does stay black and the screen of my Laptop starts to stutter. The LED an the external Monitor indicates a signal. After a while a picture appears on the monitor and unity freezes.
2. The monitor is already connected when powering on the laptop lightdm comes up in dual screen mode and emediatly freezes. Even after restarting lightdm from the terminal it again freezes right after startup.

Using my HDTV everything works fine!

I found several bugs fitting my problem but these are quite old and there are no solutions. My issue seems to be duplicate of https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/964231. I did not yet try the workaround.

What I have done so far:

- deleted ~/.config/monitors.xml => no result
- checked modes using xrandr => wrong refresh rate seems to used for monitor

  - set different refresh rate using xrandr to 60Hz while enabling it in system settings => monitor shows picture correctly and things work fine until suspend/hibernat/logoff/reboot

I tried to check the update history to see if there have been any relevant updates but synaptic does only show updates until 19th of june. I think I updated the system recently using the update manager.

Does anybody have similar problems or can even provide a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I just double checked that behavior with another monitor (Ilyama 27" FHD) and everything works like a charm! So the problem seem to be directly related with the Benq monitor. Is there a place despite the monitors.xml file where settings related to certain monitors are stored?